# getting mysql Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I am build a basic application with golang, i am using github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver. I am connecting to clearDB mysql on heroku but every time i'm getting

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, price from product where id = ?' at line 1

I can't under stand why, this is the piece of code that i'm using for the query the product database.

```
   id := c.Param("id")
    row := db.QueryRow("select id, desc, price from product where id = ?;", id)
            err := row.Scan(&product.Id, &product.desc, &product.price)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `;` from the SQL statement?

Comment: "desc" is a MySQL keyword: you need to quote it with backticks.

Comment: `DESC` is actually a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Most MySQL keywords can be used without quoting, but reserved words are a subset of those keywords that must be quoted. I think it's best to just avoid using them as column names to begin with, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a keyword so you get in trouble when you also named a column `desc`.

With MySQL you need to quote the name with backticks, like so:

```
"select id, `desc`, price from product where id = ?"
```